# setState inside for loop doesn't update state correctly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I have 3 divs. Every one will have class active when I click in specific button. Every div of them has a state variable whenever it's true I add className='active' to the div connected to it:

When I click on the button the state changes but the div doesn't get class active

```
async activeLang(e) {

  let lang = e.target.getAttribute('lang');

  for (const key in this.state.status) {

    if (key === lang) {
      await this.setState(state => {
        state.status[key] = true
      })
    }else{
      await this.setState(state => {
        state.status[key] = false
      })
    }
  
  }

  console.log(this.state.status);
}
```

when I change the function to this it works:

```
   activeLang(e) {
    let lang = e.target.getAttribute('lang');

    this.setState({
      status:{
       en: false,
       ar: false,
       fr: false,
      }
    })

    this.setState(state => {
      state.status[lang] = true
    })

    console.log(this.state.status);
  }
```

================================================

```
<ul>
 <li lang="en" onClick={this.activeLang} className={this.state.status.en ? 'active' : '' }>EN</li>
 <li lang="ar" onClick={this.activeLang} className={this.state.status.ar ? 'active' : ''}>AR</li>
 <li lang="fr" onClick={this.activeLang} className={this.state.status.fr ? 'active' : ''}>FR</li>
</ul>
```

================================================

```
<div className={this.state.status.en ? 'to-input en active' : 'to-input en'}>
 <input required type='text' onKeyUp={this.onInputChange} />
 <label title='Category name' placeholder='Ex. Business Cards'></label>
</div>

<div className={this.state.status.ar ? 'to-input ar active' : 'to-input ar'}>
 <input required type='text' onKeyUp={this.onInputChange} />
 <label title='اسم الفئة' placeholder='مثال: كروت العمل'></label>
</div>

<div className={this.state.status.fr ? 'to-input fr active' : 'to-input fr'}>
 <input required type='text' onKeyUp={this.onInputChange} />
 <label title='Nom de catégorie' placeholder='Ex. Cartes de visite'></label>
</div>
```

[image: fig 1]

Comment: You can't use setState in a loop. setState is _not_ immediate, it gets schedules, and -and this is the important part- only the **last** setState "wins" by the time the state update actually runs. So never use setState inside a loop. Do your data transforms, and all your other work, and then only call setState _once_ with the new state. That's the point of setState: it updates your component from its previous state, to its new state. Don't use it for anything intermediary.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it in a loop. Just call it once:

```
const lang = e.target.getAttribute('lang');
this.setState(state => ({
   ...state,
   status: Object.keys(state.status).reduce((acc,key) => ({
     ...acc,
     [key]:state.status[key] === lang // set all statuses to false except for `lang`
   }),{});
});
```

EDIT:

Further, `setState` doesn't return a promise, you can't `await` it. It does accept a callback, but that's not the best solution here (see above).

You should never call `setState` in a loop, messed up stuff will happen.

EDIT #2:

I've got a better solution for your state from the looks of it. Only one lang can have status active at a time, so you don't need `status` - all you need is to know what the activated language is, hence:

```js
const state = { activatedLang: 'en' } // or 'fr' or 'ar'
```

Then you can just do this:

```js
this.setState({ activatedLang: e.target.getAttribute('lang') });
```

Comment: Your answer is really good. I didn't know about 3 dots operator, I just searched for it and  It will help a lot. Thanks.